# Number of Total orders of a dependency graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations

Define a dependency graph to be a graph $G=(V,E)$ such that an edge between vertices $v$ and $u$ in $V$ is present if $v<u$ i.e. $v$ comes before $u$ in our ordering (I'm not very concise here, I just want to give you my idea).

My quesion now is how many total orders do we have on such a graph ? Is there a closed formula for this?

What I thought of doing is make something like a decision tree that has as root the first element in the ordering and as leaves the final one and do topological sorting on the graph to produce paths from the root to the leaves

As a concrete example lets look at the graph below. I know that it has 30 total orders.

[image]

Comment: I think without more information about the graph all you can say is that it's somewhere between 1 and $|V|!$, which is not very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears in your example that your dependency graph consists of a collection of total orders, each independent from each other.  With this restriction, the solution you seek is $$\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_k!}$$

Where there are $k$ total orders, and the $i^\textrm{th}$ contains $n_i$ elements, and there are $n=n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k$ total elements in your graph (not counting the max and min).

In the example shown $n_1=2, n_2=1, n_3=2, n=5$.

The explanation is as follows: we begin with $n!$ orders on the $n$ elements.  However, within each of the $k$ columns, we must choose a linear order that respects the original order of that column; exactly $\frac{1}{n_i!}$ of the linear orders respects the order of the $i^\textrm{th}$ column.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't think of using multinomial coefficients for this :D Now I see it !